# Can not configure OpenCv and PCL with XCode project on macOS

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, cmake

I am trying to create a new XCode project. I already configured opencv, but now i need both opencv and pcl libraries. I tried to make a makefile.txt, but i got the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd', needed by `SurfaceDetection'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SurfaceDetection.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

this is my cmakefile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.1)

project (SurfaceDetection)

find_package(PCL REQUIRED COMPONENTS)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (SurfaceDetection main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (SurfaceDetection ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what caused this error. You can check out what system version is your macos, once updated to macos 11.1, you have to reinstall command line tools and redirect the sdks of the project.